# Performing linq search using substring - is there a better way?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and have started writing queries using linq.

I have a Store table where each store has a name field. One of the searches I want to do is by initial letter and I'm trying to find the best way of achieving it. By best I mean most efficient.

Most searches only look for one key, 'A', 'B', 'C' etc but one of the searches is different in that the group '0-9' will contain a list of keys, one for 0, one for 1 etc. So my starting point is a list of some kind.

I then need to say if a Store name starts with any key in the list, because a Store does not store the initial letter in the table.

There are 2 things I'm looking for help with. Firstly how to get the linq working as I've outlined. Secondly, any advice as to whether there this is the best/only approach to bringing back the data or whether there may be a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not very clear, but from what I understand you want to search for stores which begin with a key found in a list of keys. You can achieve that like this:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "M" };
var result = stores.Where(store => keys.Any(key => store.Name.StartsWith(key));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the queries can differ, then for the letters:

```
stores.Where(s=>s.Name.First == c);
```

And for numerals:

```
stores.Where(char.IsDigit);
```

If they must be the same, then I suggest a character range:

```
stores.Where(s=> c1 <= s.Name.First && s.Name.First <= c2)
```

You can represent the ranges by Tuples if you want:

```
Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('A', 'A');
//Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('0', '9');
stores.Where(s=> range.Item1 <= s.Name.First && s.Name.First <= range.Item2)
```

EDIT: Using the function in the Entities Framework

```
Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('A', 'A');
//Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('0', '9');
stores.Where(s=> range.Item1 <= s.Name.Substring(0, 1) && s.Name.Substring(0, 1) <= range.Item2)
```

Comment: Using `First()` this way in an expression is not supported by Entity Framework. It will throw runtime exceptions (after you have made the code compilable at all).

Comment: Interesting. Instead, use indexing or one of the EF extensions. The basic form of the solution should work.

Comment: @Slauma - yes you're right, I'm struggling to find a syntax that gives a 'between' function - string[0] doesn't work, I could use the tuple method if converted to string (seems wrong) and the list method above will work but it willmean changes to the table, so I'll avoid that unless necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx. Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a more specific question on another thread.

Here is the answer:

[Linq to entities - first letter of string between 2 keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306034/linq-to-entities-first-letter-of-string-between-2-keys)