# Linq to entities - first letter of string between 2 keys

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and have come across an issue with the lack of support for certain extensions.

I have 2 keys (both char) `fromKey` and `toKey` and am looking to construct a `Where` statement that will search a list of `Stores`, and select where the first letter of `Store.Name` is between `fromKey` and `toKey`.

`string[0]` does not work, `Substring` does not work - anyone got any ideas how to get round this?

Code for substring method:

```
public static IQueryable<Store> FindActiveByName()
{
    var r = new ReadRepo<Store>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

    Tuple<string, string> range = Tuple.Create("0", "9");
    return r.Find().Where(s => range.Item1 <= s.Name.Substring(0, 1) &&
                               s.Name.Substring(0, 1) <= range.Item2);
}
```

Gives me an error:

> Operator <= cannot be applied to string

UPDATE

Anwser provided by nemesV

```
    public static IQueryable<Store> FindActiveByName()
    {
        Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('R', 'S');

        var r = new ReadRepo<Store>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        var keys = Enumerable
            .Range(range.Item1, (int)range.Item2 - (int)range.Item1 + 1)
            .Select(k => ((char)k).ToString());

        return r.Find(s => keys.Contains(s.Name.Substring(0, 1)));
    }
```

Comment: substring should work. Can you post your code what you have so far?

Comment: @nemesv - this is the code. Obviously tuple will be fed to method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have EF at hand so maybe this is also not working, but you can try the following workaround:

First generate a string with the `from` `to` letters. And then you can use `Contains` to check whether the first character of the `Name` is in the generated letters:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Store> FindActiveByName()
{
    var r = new ReadRepo<Store>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

    Tuple<char, char> range = Tuple.Create('0', '9');

    var letters = Enumerable
                     .Range(range.Item1, (int)range.Item2 - (int)range.Item1 + 1)
                     .Select(x => ((char)x).ToString()

    return r.Find().Where(s => letters.Contains(s.Name.Substring(0, 1)));
}
```

Or you have the obviously working workaround:

- Write the query in SQL (EF has API to execute any arbitrary query and build entities form it)
- Insert a `.ToArray()` before the `Where` which will force the query evaluation and the `Name.Substring` comparison will be done on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like this :

```
string[] data = { "Alex", "Bob", "John", "Danny", "Roy" };
char fromKey = 'A', toKey = 'D';
var query = data.Where(d => (int)d.First() >= (int)fromKey && (int)d.First() <= (int)toKey);
```

The query contains `Alex, Bob and Danny`

Its just an example. You can change it according to your need. Hope this will help.

Comment: Singh C - No i'm afraid that First() isnt supported either. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem your code actually has is that the .NET `string` class does not have overloaded `<=` and `>=` operators. So, the code does not compile (it has nothing to do with Entity Framework). Instead of the operators you can use the `string.CompareTo` method:

```
public static IQueryable<Store> FindActiveByName()
{
    var r = new ReadRepo<Store>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

    Tuple<string, string> range = Tuple.Create("0", "9");
    return r.Find().Where(s => 
        range.Item1.CompareTo(s.Name.Substring(0, 1)) <= 0 &&
        s.Name.Substring(0, 1).CompareTo(range.Item2) <= 0);
}
```

This compiles and works with Entity Framework and creates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
FROM [dbo].[Stores] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (@p__linq__0 <= (SUBSTRING([Extent1].[Name], 0 + 1, 1)))
  AND ((SUBSTRING([Extent1].[Name], 0 + 1, 1)) <= @p__linq__1)
```

The two SQL parameters `p__linq__0` and `p__linq__1` will be set as your passed in values `"0"` and `"9"` when the query is executed.